# sending post/get request to another site without leaving current site

Tags: php, xml, web-services, curl

I am developing a payment confirmation module. 
When a buyer successfully confirms his payment, the gateway redirects him/her to my success url as:

http://mysite.com/success.php?oid=P01&amt=100&refId=TXN3456

The gateway has provision to verify the current transaction using their transaction verification url as:

https://paymentgateway.com/epay/transverify.php?oid=P01&amt=100&refId=TXN3456

This url accepts POST/GET requests and returns xml response as

```
<response>
<status>Success</status>
</response>
```

or

```
<response>
<status>Failed</status>
</response>
```

Now my problem is that how can I the send the confirmation request to the gateway without leaving my site, so that i can update my order payment status on successful verification response. As a solution i tried to send an ajax request to the payment gateway, but may be due to cross domain request limitation, i was not able to do so. Is their any other method to send this request and get the response?

Ok as per suggestion I used cURL to get the response successfully, :)

My code:

```
<?php

$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://paymentgateway.com/epay/transverify.php");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);

$data = array(
'oid' => 'P01',
'amt' => '100',
'rid' => 'TXN3456'
);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);

$contents = curl_exec($ch);

curl_close($ch);

echo $contents;
?>
```

I just need the simple thing now, how to compare the result for success or failed? As the returned result ($contents) is an xml data? Thanks!

Comment: @NathanSrivi ya off course, if you can elaborate (with a gud example code) to handle returned xml data, i would be greatfully thankful to you. :)

Comment: https://paymentgateway.com/epay/transverify.php?oid=P01&amt=100&refId=TXN3456 this url shows 404 error. give correct url

Comment: @NathanSrivi that's just a sample url not the real one, as I said in the question the request url returns xml data as response, so my question is how do you extract the response value that is Success or Failed from the xml data?

Comment: Dipendra Gurung give me your original url. i can send a clear script

Answer (score 0):

use [simplexml_load_file](http://php.net/manual/en/function.simplexml-load-file.php)

```
<?php

$xml = simplexml_load_file($your url);

print_r($xml);

?>
```

simply you got a array response.